# Search Jira for open tickets with my name commented somewhere in the ticket

Tags: jira

I am trying to create a custom search for Jira looking for tickets that have had my user name commented within the tickets but only including tickets that are open in some way. These could be any kind of ticket.

The search I have tried is

(summary ~ currentUser() OR description ~ currentUser() OR comment ~ currentUser()) AND (resolution != Done OR resolution != Fixed)

However this is returning a list that includes done and fixed tickets.

A new better search or a suggestion as to how to improve the search above would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main field for opened/closed tickets to check is `status`. `resolution` is not accurate enough. You can use the following search:

```
(summary ~ currentUser() OR description ~ currentUser() OR comment ~ currentUser()) AND status != Done AND status != Closed
```

It will look for your user in any of these fields: summary, description or comment and retrieve tickets that are not done nor closed.

Hope it helps!

Comment: great that works perfectly thanks, has also highlighted a load of tickets that haven't been closed properly :)